# How do I make a text box display the last entry made into a database a mysql table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to display the last entry made in the database table inside of a text box. Currently all the entries are being displayed in text boxes but i want just one text box that contains the last entry i made into the database table. These is what the output looks like:

[image: output]

This is the code that I used to generate the output:

```
<?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "new");
if(!$conn){
die("connection error". mysqli_connect_error());
}
/*else{

    echo"connection successful";
}
*/
$connectDb=mysqli_select_db($conn,"new");
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select name from new");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php  echo $row['name']; ?>" readonly>
<?php
```

}

Comment: Database tables have no inherent ordering. How do you define the "last" entry? Do do perhaps have an ID or date field in your table by which you could order your query? For instance if you have an auto-increment ID column in your table then you could write `SELECT name FROM new ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1` to get only the most recently-added record.

Comment: Yes I have an ID field, i just tried your suggestion and it works! Thanks a bunch mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database tables have no inherent ordering. How do you define the "last" entry?

If, for example, you have an ID or date column in your table, you could use that to order your data by time of creation.

For instance if you have an auto-increment ID column in your table then you could write

```
SELECT name FROM new ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

to get only the most recently-added record.

Live demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/jaXDboLq

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "new");
if(!$conn){
       die("connection error". mysqli_connect_error());
}
/*else{

    echo"connection successful";
}
*/
$connectDb=mysqli_select_db($conn,"new");
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT name FROM new ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php  echo $row['name']; ?>" readonly>
<?php
}
```